# Play Framework Slick HikariCP Error

Tags: scala, playframework, version, slick, hikaricp

I guess I'm hitting into some sort of class in compatibility error when I tried to use Play Framework + Slick + HikariCP:

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:170) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:130) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:128) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:120) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1361) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) ~[scala-library-2.11.6.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariConfig : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

This is what I have in my sbt:

```
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.0",
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc4",
"com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.3.7"
```

I'm using Play 2.3.4 and Scala 2.11.5! Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. I'm running Java 7, so I had to use the following as my dependency:

```
"com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP-java6" % "2.3.7"
```

as per HirakiCP's documentation that can be found here:

https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP